# block with limitation in Views block display in Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views

i am developing a web site with Drupal and i want to display a block showing 10 last stories in the site.

i guess to use Views modules to do it,but i don't know how to add limitation (just 10 last records) to views.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Views is definitely your answer here, as this is what Views make real sort work of.

Two important sections in views to pay attention to to make this work for you:

- 'Items per page' - set this to 10
- 'Sort criteria' - set this to last updated date descending
- Maybe even a 'Filter' to ensure only published nodes are in the view and the node type is 'Story'

Hope this helps